# How to check radio button for gender selection in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

I want to click on radio button, if radio button is already selected then it should skip for the selection.

For more details on this visit [this site](http://automationpractice.com), go to the **Signed in option** -> **Create an account**, then you will be able to getting the page, that is provided to the screenshot.

Refer Image:

[image]

Comment: You need to search on google then post questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Find the workable code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@class='login']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='email_create']")).sendKeys("abc123_1@yahoo.com");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@id='SubmitCreate']")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='id_gender1']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

You can put `implicit waits` as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to check that the `MR` radio button is selected or not? If `MR` radio button is not selected then only if condition will execute.

```
WebElement MR = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/span/input[@id='id_gender1']"));
if(!MR.isSelected())
{
    MR.click();
}
```

> OR

If you want to check that the `Mrs` radio button is selected or not? If `Mrs` radio button is not selected then only if condition will execute.

```
WebElement Mrs = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/span/input[@id='id_gender2']"));
if(!Mrs.isSelected())
{
    Mrs.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is really helpful.

Comment: If this my answer is `helpful` to you, then please mark this answer as `Accepted`